# string assignment giving .Input string was not in a correct format in the above code

Tags: c#

I want to do is to build a string with the value below.

desired output:

```
<script async    src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
                    <!-- www.pmgurus.com -->
                    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
                        style="display: inline-block; width: 154px; height: 300px"
                        data-ad-client="ca-pub-7078262119581230"
                        data-ad-slot="8368493350"></ins>
                    <script>
                        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
                    </script>
```

My code :

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 sb.AppendLine(String.Format(@"<script async src=""//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js""></script>
                    <!-- www.pmgurus.com -->
                    <ins class=""adsbygoogle""
                        style=""display: inline-block; width: 154px; height: 300px""
                        data-ad-client=""ca-pub-7078262119581230""
                        data-ad-slot=""8368493350""></ins>
                    <script>
                        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
                    </script>"));
```

This code compiles properly when it is built.

When its executes however I get

Input string was not in a correct format in the above code. I am not sure why it doesnot run.

Comment: Why are you using `string.Format` when you're not providing any arguments? Just use a verbatim string literal...

Comment: Let me try removing that. string.format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you have already been told that you should remove the innecessary call to `string.Format`, to answer your question, the reason of the error you get is because your string has a `{}`. Curly brackets are reserved characters as they are used to indicate a placeholder. If you need to display them with a `string.Format`, you should escape them by doubling them:

```
....).push({{}});
```

But if you don't need any special formatting, just remove the method call and you are done.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need for `string.Format`, nor even a `StringBuilder` unless you intend on concatenating a lot to it. Simply use something like this to initialize it :

```
string sb = @"<script async src=""//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js""></script>
                    <!-- www.pmgurus.com -->
                    <ins class=""adsbygoogle""
                        style=""display: inline-block; width: 154px; height: 300px""
                        data-ad-client=""ca-pub-7078262119581230""
                        data-ad-slot=""8368493350""></ins>
                    <script>
                        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
                    </script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you need to use String.Format at all in this example. You could just do:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine(@"<script async src=""//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js""></script>
                <!-- www.pmgurus.com -->
                <ins class=""adsbygoogle""
                    style=""display: inline-block; width: 154px; height: 300px""
                    data-ad-client=""ca-pub-7078262119581230""
                    data-ad-slot=""8368493350""></ins>
                <script>
                    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
                </script>");
```

If, however, you need to use String.Format with a string that includes curly braces, you have to escape them using double braces, as in {{ and }}. So your previous example with String.Format would be:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine(String.Format(@"<script async src=""//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js""></script>
                <!-- www.pmgurus.com -->
                <ins class=""adsbygoogle""
                    style=""display: inline-block; width: 154px; height: 300px""
                    data-ad-client=""ca-pub-7078262119581230""
                    data-ad-slot=""8368493350""></ins>
                <script>
                    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({{}});
                </script>"));
```

You'll notice the {{}} near the end at the call to "push". This will render out as a single curly brace set {} in the result.

Comment: I got it. Thanks. I removed the string.format and it worked. I understood the culprit here was {}.

Answer (score 0):

```
    string xy="<script async    src='//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js'></script> <!-- www.pmgurus.com --> <ins class='adsbygoogle' style='display: inline-block; width: 154px; height: 300px'  data-ad-client='ca-pub-7078262119581230' data-ad-slot='8368493350'></ins>  <script>  (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});  </script>";
```

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine(xy);